# How shared convolutional layers are fixed in training Faster R-CNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I am looking through the [code in the library](https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn). In the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.01497.pdf), (page 6, second column, first para), it is stated as convolutional layers are fixed (during training in third and fourth steps) and tuned the RPN layers and Fast RCNN layers.

Which portion of the code is taking care of it?

I looked at the code and Solver.cpp is the one controlling Forward/Backward.
I don't see implementation of fixing convolutional layers there.

Then all prototxt files have similar implementations for layers.

How this fixing convolutional layers in training is implemented?

Comment: look at `lr_mult` of the layers

Comment: Yes I found lr_mult are 0.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When freezing a layer during fine-tuning, one usually sets

```
param { lr_mult: 0 }
```

for that layer, this way caffe does not update the weights for this layer.